How to increase right inner block padding with Metropolis Beamer theme?
With the Metropolis Beamer theme, I'm missing the right inner block padding. It seems to be specifically related to lists inside blocks. An exemplary source:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
    \metroset{block=fill}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}

\begin{block}{Block title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sit amet posuere enim, a feugiat risus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque fringilla faucibus leo, quis aliquam augue porta vel. Nullam sit amet mauris aliquam, sodales eros a, pharetra neque. Aenean in quam eu metus fringilla porta. Ut at dolor massa.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}

This source produces the following result, where the word “In” almost touches the right block margin:

Live demo: https://www.overleaf.com/7135396712dmpdvdwdbbtk#dcc769
Is there any to increase the right block padding to avoid such cases? I even wouldn't mind shifting the entire list slightly to the left, since the horizontal space before the bullet seems to be unnecessary large for a first-level item.

You could use the moloch theme instead. It is a modernised fork of the metropolis theme and avoids this problem automatically:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\molochset{block=fill}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}

\begin{block}{Block title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sit amet posuere enim, a feugiat risus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque fringilla faucibus leo, quis aliquam augue porta vel. Nullam sit amet mauris aliquam, sodales eros a, pharetra neque. Aenean in quam eu metus fringilla porta. Ut at dolor massa.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}


If you really must use the outdated metropolis theme, you could combine it with the tcolorbox inner theme. This will replace the blocks from metropolis with tcolorboxes. This avoids the problem and in addition allows you to easily modify the padding:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\metroset{block=fill}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}

\begin{block}{Block title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sit amet posuere enim, a feugiat risus. In hac habitasse platea \end{itemize}
\end{block}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  right=0.3cm
}

\begin{block}{Block title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sit amet posuere enim, a feugiat risus. In hac habitasse platea \end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thanks, I didn't know about the moloch theme, but I will try it.
